# python remove duplicate dictionaries from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries

```
l = [
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs'},
{'firstname': 'john', 'surname': 'smith'},
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs'},
{'firstname': 'jane', 'surname': 'bloggs'}
]
```

how do i remove duplicates i.e. `{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs'}` appears twice so would want it only appearing once?

Comment: What have you already tried? We're not here to just give you code.

Comment: Actually, I've looked in Google for some very simple problems that I know can be done easily in Python.  And StackOverflow has most definitely provided "just the code" in my assistance, which is all I really need.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Something like this should do the stuff :

```
result = [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in l)]
```

first, I transform the inital dict in a list of tuples, then I put them into a set (that removes duplicates entries), and then back into a dict.

Comment: Get rid of the brackets in the `set` call -- a generator expression is what you want there, not a list comprehension. Otherwise, nice.

Comment: @agf : thanks, I'll have to lose this bad habit ;)

Comment: How to do this if I want to use say two out of total 10 columns?

Answer (score 14):

```
import itertools

import operator

import pprint

l = [

{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs'},

{'firstname': 'john', 'surname': 'smith'},

{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs'},

{'firstname': 'jane', 'surname': 'bloggs'}

]

getvals = operator.itemgetter('firstname', 'surname')

l.sort(key=getvals)

result = []

for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, getvals):
    result.append(next(g))

l[:] = result

pprint.pprint(l)
```

Comment: this is a nice solution if you have specific fields you want to de-duplicate on, and don't want to de-dup on all fields present in the dictionary.