# How to remove duplicates in a csv file based on two columns?

Tags: python

I have a csv file like this :

```
column1    column2

john       kerry
adam       stephenson
ashley     hudson
john       kerry
etc..
```

I want to  remove duplicates from this file, to get only :

```
column1    column2

john       kerry
adam       stephenson
ashley     hudson
```

I wrote this script that removes duplicates based on lastnames, but I need to remove duplicates based on lastnames AND firstname.

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('myfilewithduplicates.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
writer=csv.writer(open('myfilewithoutduplicates.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

lastnames = set()
for row in reader:
    if row[1] not in lastnames:
        writer.writerow(row)
        lastnames.add( row[1] )
```

Comment: "I wrote this script that removes duplicates based on names, but I need to remove duplicates based on name AND firstname." I'm confused here. When you say name do you mean first name, last name or a concatenation? Your script only works on last names.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I want to remove duplicates based on lastnames (column2) and firstnames (column1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're really close. Use those columns as the set entry

```
entries = set()

for row in reader:
   key = (row[0], row[1]) # instead of just the last name

   if key not in entries:
      writer.writerow(row)
      entries.add(key)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can now use the .drop_duplicates method in pandas. I would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
toclean = pd.read_csv('myfilewithduplicates.csv')
deduped = toclean.drop_duplicates([col1,col2])
deduped.to_csv('myfilewithoutduplicates.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to create a unique set of rows using the following technique (adopted from @CedricJulien from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090758/python-remove-duplicate-dictionaries-from-a-list) post). You lose the `DictWriter` benefit of having the column names stored in each row, but it should work for you case:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('testcsv1.csv', 'r') as f:
...   reader = csv.reader(f)
...   uniq = [list(tup) for tup in set([tuple(row) for row in reader])]
...
>>> with open('nodupes.csv', 'w') as f:
...   writer=csv.writer(f)
...   for row in uniq:
...     writer.writerow(row)
```

This uses the same technique used by @CedricJulien, which is a nice one-liner to remove the duplicate rows (defined as the same first and last name). This uses the `DictReader`/`DictWriter` classes:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('testcsv1.csv', 'r') as f:
...   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
...   rows = [row for row in reader]
...
>>> uniq = [dict(tup) for tup in set(tuple(person.items()) for person in rows)]
>>> with open('nodupes.csv', 'w') as f:
...   headers = ['column1', 'column2']
...   writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
...   writer.writerow(dict((h, h) for h in headers))

...   for row in uniq:
...     writer.writerow(row)
...
```