# Django: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, django

My snippet from my function,

it just fetches from as django queryset objects and converting into list to remove duplicates using itemgetter and itertools method like [python remove duplicate dictionaries from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090758/python-remove-duplicate-dictionaries-from-a-list/7091256#7091256)

```
   hc = HomeContractorDetails.objects.filter(category=domain_obj.category,city__icontains=domain_obj.city).values(*args)
    _arg = list(args)
    _arg.remove('id')
    hc = list(hc)
    print _arg,hc

    n= hc.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(_arg))
```

ERROR FOR THE ABOVE STMT

```
['con_name', 'rating', 'review_no'] [{'rating': u'4.32', 'review_no': u'51', 'id': 3781, 'con_name': u"Carter's Mechanical, Inc."}, {'rating': u'4.02', 'review_no': u'29', 'id': 3782, 'con_name': u'All Mechanical Plumbing & Heating, Inc.'}, {'rating': u'4.17', 'review_no': u'5', 'id': 3783, 'con_name': u'Marcelo Construction'}, {'rating': u'4.63', 'review_no': u'34', 'id': 3784, 'con_name': u'Jay Ell Plumbing and Heating Company, Inc.'}, {'rating': u'4.94', 'review_no': u'24', 'id': 3785, 'con_name': u'Franco Belli Plumbing and Heating and Sons, Inc.'}]

File "/home/gridlex/workspace/HA/article/views.py" in fetch_contractor_tables
      213.     n= hc.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(_arg))

    Exception Type: TypeError at /article/top-rated-plumbing-contractors-in-new-york
    Exception Value: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The variable hc prints list of dict values.But I could not able to sort using itemgetter keyfunc.

Could you help me to identify this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to expand.

```
n = hc.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*_arg))
```

Answer (score 0):

A list is not a hashable type. Use a different sequence type, such as a `tuple` where you currently have `list`.

However, given that `_arg` is a sequence, is that what you want for your `itemgetter`? Or do you want one of the values in it?