# How to remove dictionary from list of dictionary if value repeats in items

Tags: python, dictionary

List of dictionary is below

```
l = [
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'ABCD', 'tile' : 'DE'},
{'firstname': 'john', 'surname': 'DEF', 'tile' : 'BC'},
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs', 'tile' : 'DE'},
{'firstname': 'jane', 'surname': 'HH', 'tile' : 'AD'}
]
```

Need to delete item from `l` if `firstname` and `tile` matches

pseudo code

```
for i in l:
   if i['firstname'] + i['tile'] in l:
        l.pop(i)
```

I have gone through [python remove duplicate dictionaries from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090758/python-remove-duplicate-dictionaries-from-a-list)

its removing entire dict matches

Also gone through second answer [python remove duplicate dictionaries from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090758/python-remove-duplicate-dictionaries-from-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
l = [
    {"firstname": "joe", "surname": "ABCD", "tile": "DE"},
    {"firstname": "john", "surname": "DEF", "tile": "BC"},
    {"firstname": "joe", "surname": "bloggs", "tile": "DE"},
    {"firstname": "jane", "surname": "HH", "tile": "AD"},
]

out = {}
for d in reversed(l):
    out[(d["firstname"], d["tile"])] = d

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"firstname": "jane", "surname": "HH", "tile": "AD"},
    {"firstname": "joe", "surname": "ABCD", "tile": "DE"},
    {"firstname": "john", "surname": "DEF", "tile": "BC"},
]
```

Comment: why reversed, other code is also working

Comment: @sim I reversed the list because I want to keep the first occurrence. If you don't need that, you can remove `reversed()`

Comment: Why not just set d as the default instead?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yup, You're right...sometimes I complicate things :)

Comment: Actually I meant `for d in l:
    out.setdefault((d["firstname"], d["tile"]), d)`. But yours works, too.

Comment: Although yours changes the order (and not just reversing it), so maybe the forwards-iteration with setdefault is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Extended this SO answer [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419576/8353711)

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'ABCD', 'tile' : 'DE'},
{'firstname': 'john', 'surname': 'DEF', 'tile' : 'BC'},
{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'bloggs', 'tile' : 'DE'},
{'firstname': 'jane', 'surname': 'HH', 'tile' : 'AD'}
]


group = [(item['firstname'], item['tile']) for item in l]

def list_duplicates(seq):
    tally = defaultdict(list)
    for i,item in enumerate(seq):
        tally[item].append(i)
    return ((key,locs) for key,locs in tally.items() 
                            if len(locs)>=1)

new_l = []
for dup in list_duplicates(group):
    new_l.append(l[dup[1][0]])
  
new_l
```

**Output:**

```
[{'firstname': 'joe', 'surname': 'ABCD', 'tile': 'DE'},
 {'firstname': 'john', 'surname': 'DEF', 'tile': 'BC'},
 {'firstname': 'jane', 'surname': 'HH', 'tile': 'AD'}]
```